# Assembly | Convert 32 bit negative number to its un-signed rerepresentation (also in 32 bit)

Tags: assembly

I have an int (16 bit) array: {10,-20,30,-40} i want:

1. to sum the array and display the result as unsinged 32 bit number
2. to sum the array and display the result as 32 bit number (signed)

which means:

```
32 bit  un-signed  : 131052
32 bit negative Number positive : -20
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear exactly what you're after. Three obvious possibilities would looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() { 

    short array[] = {10, -20, 30, -40};

    std::cout << std::accumulate(array, array+4, (unsigned short)0) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::accumulate(array, array+4, 0U) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::accumulate(array, array+4, (short)0) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not at all sure how you think you can get 131052 as a result though -- that's not what you'll get from either a 16-bit or a 32-bit sum.